# Calling module imported using 'import' in Javascript eval function

Tags: javascript, amd

I import a module using import. I would like to use this module in evaluate (eval function)

```
// Handlebars
import Handlebars from 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js'

export const SecondModule = {

   function test(a)
   {
       let text = 'Handlebars.compile("{{hello}}")'

       // Let's call eval now which has Handlebars in it
       eval(text)
   }
}
```

This throws an error that Handlebars is not defined. How do I access Handlebars from eval? I understand that imports are compiled in AMD format during compile time.